# Tensorflow - running total

Tags: tensorflow

How can I add the number 5 after every iteration of the loop?

I want to do something like this:

```
weight = 0.225

for i in range(10):
    weight += 5
    print (weight)
```

Here is how I am trying in tensorflow but it never updates the weight

```
import tensorflow as tf
def dummy(x):
    weights['h0'] = tf.add(weights['h0'], 5)
    res = tf.add(weights['h0'], x)
    return res

# build computational graph
a = tf.placeholder('float', None)
d = dummy(a)
weights = {
    'h0': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
}
# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# create session and run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        print (sess.run(d, feed_dict={a: [2]}))
# close session
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an operation explicitly created for adding a value and assigning the result back to the input node: [`tf.assign_add`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add)

You should use it instead of `tf.assing` + `tf.add`.

Also, it's more important that you understand why you previous code won't work.

```
weights['h0'] = tf.add(weights['h0'], 5)
res = tf.add(weights['h0'], x)
```

At the fist line, you're defining a **node** add, whose inputs are `weights['h0']` and `5` **and** you're assigning this **node** to a **python variable** `weights['h0']`.

Now, thus, `weights['h0']` is a python variable holding a tensorflow node.

In the next line, you're defining another add node, between the previous node and `x`, and you return this node.

When the graph is evaluated, you evaluate the node pointed by `res`, that force the evaluation of the previous node (because res is a function of the node holded by `weights['h0']`).

The problem is the that your assignment at line `1` is a **python** assignment and not a tensorflow assignment.
Thus that assign operation is executed only in the python environment but it has no defined an assign node into the tensorflow graph.

P.S: when you use `with` you're defining a context manager that handles the closing operations for you. You can thus remove `sess.close()` because is executed automatically when you exit from that context

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is an assign operator

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign

```
weights['h0'] = tf.assign(weights['h0'], tf.add(weights['h0'], 5))
```